# How to get tomorrows date using classic ASP

Tags: date, asp-classic

I am using the following ASP code to print today's date to the screen

```
Response.Write(WeekDayName(Weekday(Date))) & ", " & Day(Now) & dateSuffix & " " & monthname(month(date), true)
```

However, I actually need to do this for tomorrows date. Can someone please tell me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Response.Write(DateAdd("d", 1, Date))
```

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_dateadd.asp

That site has good examples and is a good reference of classic asp